# Expected value of the squared root of sum of normal random variables

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_n$ be normal random variables with mean $\mu=a$ and variance $\sigma^2=a$.

I want to show that $$E(\frac{\sqrt{1+4s}-1}{2})\neq a$$ where $s=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^nX_i^2}{n}$.

It seems exact calculation is difficult so maybe Jensen's inequality would be helpful.

Comment: So what would Jensen imply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x\mapsto\sqrt x$ is a concave function, Jensen's inequality yields
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\frac{\sqrt{1+4S_n}-1}2\right] &= \frac12(\mathbb E[\sqrt{1+4S_n}]-1)\\&\leqslant \frac12\left(\sqrt{\mathbb E[1+4S_n]}-1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\sqrt{1 + 4\mathbb E[S_n]}-1 \right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\sqrt{1+4a}-1\right).
\end{align}
Now,
$$
a = \frac12\left(\sqrt{1+4a}-1\right) \iff a=0,
$$
which is impossible since a normal random variable must have positive variance.

Comment: Thanks. The square-root function is concave. The second inequality should be $\leq$

Comment: @Probabilitystudent Thanks for pointing that out, I always get it mixed up >_<